# Nextflow script to process all files in given directory

Tags: groovy, pipeline, bioinformatics, nextflow

I have a nextflow script that runs a couple of processes on a single vcf file. The name of the file is 'bos_taurus.vcf' and it is located in the directory /input_files/bos_taurus.vcf. The directory input_files/ contains also another file 'sacharomyces_cerevisea.vcf'. I would like my nextflow script to process both files. I was trying to use a glob pattern like ch_1 = channel.fromPath("/input_files/*.vcf"), but sadly I can't find a working solution. Any help would be really appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow

nextflow.enable.dsl=2


// here I tried to use globbing

params.input_files = "/mnt/c/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/STUDIA/BIOINFORMATYKA/SEMESTR_V/PRACOWNIA_INFORMATYCZNA/nextflow/projekt/input_files/*.vcf"

params.results_dir = "/mnt/c/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/STUDIA/BIOINFORMATYKA/SEMESTR_V/PRACOWNIA_INFORMATYCZNA/nextflow/projekt/results"


file_channel = Channel.fromPath( params.input_files, checkIfExists: true )


// how can I make this process work on two files simultanously

process FILTERING {

    publishDir("${params.results_dir}/after_filtering", mode: 'copy')

    input:
    path(input_files)

    output:
    path("*")

    script:
    """
    vcftools --vcf ${input_files} --mac 1 --minQ 20 --recode  --recode-INFO-all  --out after_filtering.vcf
    """
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Note that if your VCF files are actually [bgzip](http://www.htslib.org/doc/bgzip.html) compressed and [tabix](http://www.htslib.org/doc/tabix.html) indexed, you could instead use the [fromFilePairs](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#fromfilepairs) factory method to create your input channel. For example:

```
params.vcf_files = "./input_files/*.vcf.gz{,.tbi}"
params.results_dir = "./results"


process FILTERING {

    tag { sample }

    publishDir("${params.results_dir}/after_filtering", mode: 'copy')

    input:
    tuple val(sample), path(indexed_vcf)

    output:
    tuple val(sample), path("${sample}.filtered.vcf")

    """
    vcftools \\
        --vcf "${indexed_vcf.first()}" \\
        --mac 1 \\
        --minQ 20 \\
        --recode \\
        --recode-INFO-all \\
        --out "${sample}.filtered.vcf"
    """
}

workflow {

    vcf_files = Channel.fromFilePairs( params.vcf_files, checkIfExists: true )

    FILTERING( vcf_files ).view()
}
```

Results:

```
$ nextflow run main.nf
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 22.10.0
Launching `main.nf` [thirsty_torricelli] DSL2 - revision: 8f69ad5638
executor >  local (3)
[7d/dacad6] process > FILTERING (C) [100%] 3 of 3 ✔
[A, /path/to/work/84/f9f00097bcd2b012d3a5e105b9d828/A.filtered.vcf]
[B, /path/to/work/cb/9f6f78213f0943013990d30dbb9337/B.filtered.vcf]
[C, /path/to/work/7d/dacad693f06025a6301c33fd03157b/C.filtered.vcf]
```

Note that [BCFtools](https://samtools.github.io/bcftools/) is actively maintained and is intended as a replacement for VCFtools. In a production pipeline, BCFtools should be preferred.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a little example for starters. First, you should specify a unique output name in each process. Currently, `after_filtering.vcf` is hardcoded so this will overwrite each other once copied to the publishDir. You can do that with the `baseName` operator as below and permanently store it in the input file channel, first element being the sample name and second one the actual file. I made an example process that just runs `head` on the vcf, you can then adapt as needed for what you actually need.

```
#! /usr/bin/env nextflow

nextflow.enable.dsl = 2

params.input_files = "/Users/atpoint/vcf/*.vcf"
params.results_dir = "/Users/atpoint/vcf/"

// A channel that contains a map with sample name and the file itself
file_channel = Channel.fromPath( params.input_files, checkIfExists: true )
                      .map { it -> [it.baseName, it] }

// An example process just head-ing the vcf
process VcfHead {

    publishDir("${params.results_dir}/after_filtering", mode: 'copy')

    input:
    tuple val(name), path(vcf_in)

    output:
    path("*_head.vcf")

    script:
    """ 
    head -n 1 $vcf_in > ${name}_head.vcf
    """

}                      

// Run it
workflow {

    VcfHead(file_channel)

}
```

The `file_channel` channel looks like this if you add a `.view()` to it:

```
[one, /Users/atpoint/vcf/one.vcf]
[two, /Users/atpoint/vcf/two.vcf]
```

Comment: "and permanently store it in the input file channel as a map". I think you mean "and stre it in the input file channel using the [map](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#map) operator". Because what you get is not a map, it's actually an ArrayList (`java.util.ArrayList`). If instead you'd have used `tuple()` instead of the square brackets, you'd get an ArrayTuple (`nextflow.util.ArrayTuple`).

Comment: Also, it's usually better to declare the input channel inside the workflow block.

Comment: Does this make any difference other than style in terms of where one declares channels?

Comment: Addressed your comment on terminology. Thanks!

Comment: Not AFAIK. The usual preference is to minimize variable scope. If processes can only be invoked from within the scope of the workflow block, declaring them where they're going to be used keeps all of the workflow logic in one place.